# Can I give an if statement by subtracting time?

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

Is there a way to make my VBA code work for my macro? I want my macro's if function to read the first column of each worksheet in my excel (it has as many sheets as days in the exact month i'm working on), read through each cell and if the currently read cell is equal to or larger than '15 minutes compared to the first cell, then the code would execute, otherwise go to the next cell in the first column.

This is the format of the worksheets i'm working on:

| TimeStamp | Power Consumption | Power Production | Inductive Power Consumption |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.01.01. 8:12:38 +00:00 | 747 | 575 | 3333 |
| 2021.01.01. 8:17:35 +00:00 | 7674 | 576 | 3333 |

... etc ,

And my code looks something like this:

```
Sub stackoverflow()
    Dim w As Integer 'index of worksheets
    Dim i As Integer 'row index that steps through the first column
    Dim t As Integer 'reference row index i inspect the time to
    Dim x As Integer 'row index where i want my data to be printed
    Dim j As Integer 'col index
    Dim Timediff As Date  'not sure if this is even needed
        
    t = 2
    j = 1
    x = 1
    'Timediff = ("00:15:00")
                    
        For w = 3 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count        'for every sheet from the 3rd to the last
            lRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row     'find the last row in each worksheet
            lCol = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'find the last column in each worksheet
                For x = 2 To lRow
                For i = 2 To lRow
                    'If the time in cell(i,j) is >= then cell(t,j) + 15 minutes,
                    If Cells(i, j) >= DateAdd("n", 15, Cells(t, j)) Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w).Range(i, j).Copy ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range(x, j)
                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w).Range(i, j + 1).Copy ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range(x, j + 1)
                    'put the new reference point after the found 15 minute mark
                    t = i + 1
                    Else
                    End If
                            
                Next i
                Next x
        Next w
End Sub
```

So all in all I want my code to notice when the first column reaches a 15 minute mark, and execute some code (subtracting the values of the 15 minute mark from the reference where it started, put the value in the'2nd sheet, and then step to the next cell, and repeat the process).

Comment: Are the values in "TimeStamp" actual dates?

Comment: Is there some specific problem you're having with your code? FYI you can subtract 2 dates and the difference will be some number (or fractional number) of days. Since 1 / 24 / 4 would be 15mins you can compare the difference to that.

Comment: Yes the "TimeStamp" column has actual dates, in the format as shown. 
The code won't run, debugging gives me an error for the lines written inside the If statement, and even if I change the indexes that i put in as variables for actual cells, the code runs, and does absolutely nothing.. i'm kind of stuck, and don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure which information you are attempting to copy to the second worksheet but the following code should be able to get you there pretty easily.  Additionally, I've added a function that will fix the format of your TimeStamp field so that excel will recognize it and we can then do math with it

```
Sub TestA()
    Dim xlCellA As Range
    Dim xlCellB As Range
    Dim xlCellC As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
        Set xlCellA = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(2, 1)
        For i = 3 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
            lRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
            lCol = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
            Set xlCellB = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(2, 1)
            xlCellB.Value = FixFormat(xlCellB.Value)
            xlCellB.Offset(0, lCol + 1).Value = "=DATEVALUE(MID(" & xlCellB.Address & ",1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(" & xlCellB.Address & ",12,8))"
            For j = 3 To lRow
                Set xlCellC = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1)
                xlCellC.Value = FixFormat(xlCellC.Value)
                xlCellC.Offset(0, lCol + 1).Value = "=DATEVALUE(MID(" & xlCellC.Address & ",1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(" & xlCellC.Address & ",12,8))"
                If xlCellC.Offset(0, lCol + 1) - xlCellB.Offset(0, lCol + 1) >= ((1 / 24) / 4) Then
                    With xlCellA
                        .Value = xlCellC.Value
                        .Offset(0, 1).Value = xlCellC.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End With
                    Set xlCellA = xlCellA.Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        Set xlCellA = Nothing
        Set xlCellB = Nothing
        Set xlCellC = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function FixFormat(ByVal dStr As String) As String
    Dim tmpStr As String
    Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To Len(dStr)
            If Mid(dStr, i, 1) <> "." Then
                tmpStr = tmpStr & Mid(dStr, i, 1)
            Else
                If Mid(dStr, i + 1, 1) <> " " Then tmpStr = tmpStr & "-"
            End If
        Next i
        FixFormat = tmpStr
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot in understanding how to handle Excel cells in VBA! I finished the project, and the code works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what needs to happen when the 15min threshold is met but this should get you most of the way there:

```vb
Sub stackoverflow()
    
    Dim w As Long, Timediff As Double
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsData As Worksheet, wsResults As Worksheet, col As Long
    Dim baseRow As Range, dataRow As Range, rngData As Range, resultRow As Range
    
    Timediff = 1 / 24 / 4 '(15min = 1/4 of 1/24 of a day)
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook
    Set wsResults = wb.Worksheets("Results")
    
    'first row for recording results
    Set resultRow = wsResults.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    
    For w = 3 To wb.Worksheets.Count        'for every sheet from the 3rd to the last
        
        Set rngData = wb.Worksheets(w).Range("A1").CurrentRegion          'whole table
        Set rngData = rngData.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngData.Rows.Count - 1) 'exclude headers
        
        Set baseRow = rngData.Rows(1)               'set comparison row
        For Each dataRow In rngData.Rows            'loop over rows in data
            If (dataRow.Cells(1).Value - baseRow.Cells(1).Value) > Timediff Then
                
                resultRow.Cells(1).Value = dataRow.Cells(1) 'copy date
                For col = 2 To dataRow.Cells.Count          'loop columns and subtract
                    resultRow.Cells(col).Value = _
                             dataRow.Cells(col).Value - baseRow.Cells(col).Value
                Next col
                Set resultRow = resultRow.Offset(1, 0)
                Set baseRow = dataRow.Offset(1, 0)  'reset comparison row to next row
            
            End If
        Next dataRow
       
    Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was more than helpful, I really just started coding in VBA, and this helped a lot!